# Bidirectional reflection disturbance function (BRDF) for Landsat imagery in earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, atmospheric-correction

I am wanting to use various vegetation indices calculated using Landsat imagery.

I am aware that BRDF is an important correction to do, but I am unsure where to start.

Is there a product with corrections that include BRDF for Landsat?

**ANSWER** I found an answer and it a link to the code is posted below.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, and I have changed the question so that you release it from hold. But actually, the first part of the question is looking for references, while the second part is looking for examples of code to answer the question. I will be positing the second part as a stand alone question and will aim to make it more targeted.

Comment: We are happy to help with where you get stuck writing your own code but questions asking for code usually get closed for not including a code attempt.

Comment: I think it'd be better if you ask this in the developers forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-earth-engine-developers, since core developers of EE answer there ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer following Rodrigo's suggestion in the comments. Hopefully this will stave off any more negative votes on this question!

The answer can be found at the following address from a member of the developer forum called erik.

erik posted the code (in earth.engine) and the citation we should all use to reference his work!
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-earth-engine-developers/brdf$20landsat|sort:date/google-earth-engine-developers/KDqlUCj4LTs/vgijq44hBgAJ

I have copied the most important bits below:

D.P. Roy, H.K. Zhang, J. Ju, J.L. Gomez-Dans, P.E. Lewis, C.B. Schaaf, Q. Sun, J. Li, H. Huang, V. Kovalskyy, A general method to normalize Landsat reflectance data to nadir BRDF adjusted reflectance, Remote Sensing of Environment, Volume 176, April 2016, Pages 255-271

Here is the code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/3a6761dea6f1bf54b03de1b84dc375c6